# Xcode and GLFW problems

Tags: c++, xcode, glfw

I searched SO and googled a lot, but could not find an answer.
So here is my problem:
I am trying to compile on of the tests included in the GLFW download.
Its the most basic one, titled "title.c".
I added GLFW to the command-line project using the direction given here:
http://leewinder.co.uk/blog/?p=1195#sthash.XHaR6dNC.dpbs
Though I could not find the file "config.h.in" for cmake.
Now Xcode gives the following errors, and I don't know where to start looking:

[image: error]

Thanks in advance, and excuse me if the answer is too obvious! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. The undefined symbols are in the Quartz framework according to Apple Developer, so I added them and it runs just fine! Though I don't understand why this is necessary and wasn't before...